# Circuit Problem: Find Vx

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

Hello, can  anyone help me with this problem. I need to find the value of Vx but I can't seem to find any progress.
However, I do know that voltage between 6ohms and 1A is equal and that the current is equal between 3ohms, 2ohms and Vx.

However, I can't seem to move past that.

Please help me, though pls post only hints or direction of the solution [not the ans. itself,  still vying for that sense of accomplishment]

Thanks for advance.

Comment: The value of resistance is missing if you want to have one unique solution. Otherwise, the Vx voltage will be a function of the missing resistance value.

Comment: Try writing the voltage across the unknown resistor (call it Vy) as  a function of the resistor value. Then you can use that to calculate the currents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have specifically requested no solution be provided, I will give you only the general strategy for this problem and you can work the rest out yourself.

1. You will want to apply the 'node voltage' method satisfying KCL for the two 'black dot' nodes drawn in your schematic
2. As Spehro Pefhany said in his comment, you will want to create an expression relating the 1A current to the voltage across the 'mystery resistor'. This will provide you with a handy substitution that you can use to relate Vx to R with the system of 2 equations you've already built.

To check your answer, I recommend using a SPICE simulator (LTspice and TINA-TI are both free and easy to use).

Comment: This is a bit late of me but thank you very much!